# How can I translate static text in my templates that have accents?

Tags: localization

Using this help page https://craftcms.com/support/static-translations I've created a `fr.php` file in a translations folder - and it's working OK. Except when I have `"Telephone" => "Téléphone"` in the array - the two é get output as black diamonds with a question mark in.

How should I be adding Téléphone in the array so that it outputs correctly?

Many thanks
Lee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are in the process of translating one of our client sites into 16 (yes that's 16!) languages and we haven't had any issues with accented characters.

The only thing I can suggest off the top of my head is to ensure you are using UTF-8 character encoding. Pop this in your `<head>`:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'd also check that when you're saving the `fr.php` file, make sure you're saving it with a UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Thanks Jamie and Brad. Saving the file with UTF-8 encoding fixed it.